# jquery attr(readonly) function not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working with AST.Net and jQuery 1.8.3.

I want to make a textbox's readonly property to be true on pageload and false when a script runs. My code goes like this:

```
  function showdiv() {

    $("#diviv").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#txtname").attr('readonly', false);
    $("#txtmobile").attr('readonly', false);
    $("#txtemail").attr('readonly', false);
}
```

I want to make the readonly property of these three textboxes to be false when the function `showdiv` runs. Also I am making a div visible when the script runs. But it's not making it false. Please give me some suggessions how to make it run and tell me where the problem is.

Comment: Try for $("#txtname").removeAttr('readonly');

Comment: thanks i tried  it is not working in my application,but when i tried in another application it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readonly is a boolean attribute, which means that if it is present, no matter what value it has, it will be set. Since attributes are always strings, you are setting it to "false". Use prop instead.

```
   $("#txtname").prop('readonly', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("#txtmobile").prop('readonly', false);
```

OR

```
$("#<%= txtname.ClientID %>").prop('readonly', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

`readonly` is a boolean attribute, which means that if it is present, no matter what value it has, it will be set.  Since attributes are always strings, you are setting it to `"false"`.  Use `prop` instead.

```
$("#txtname").prop('readonly', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can use removeAttr in jquery.

```
 $("#txtmobile").removeAttr('readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `readonly` property of a textbox is does not take `true/false` as values, all you have to specify is the keyword `readonly` like so,

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" readonly />
```

Now, to "disable" this property, you will have to remove this using jQuery's `.removeAttr()` method,

```
$("#txtName").removeAttr("readonly");
```

[test link](http://jsfiddle.net/7HK9s/1/)

Comment: Thanks i tried it is not working in my application,but when i tried in another application it worked.can u tell where is the problem..

Comment: If you're using `asp.net`, then you'd have to bind your control like this, `$("#<%= txtname.ClientID %>")`