# Code that runs in FF does not work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have this simple code that works in FF32, but does not work in IE11. Why? Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/kaur/LjLhzd4g/

```
</tr>
<tr class="evenRow">
<td class="bold">Course Number</td>
<td><input type="text" id="course_number" name="UF-00300325672803" value="4159" size="8"></td>
<tr>
    <button id="save">Click</button>
</tr>
$('#save').click(function () {
    $(course_number).attr('readonly', true);
});
```

Comment: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/LjLhzd4g/1/). **1.** include jQuery **2.** Use correct selector to get the input. `$(course_number)` is syntax error, use `$('#course_number')`

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151882/jquery-attrreadonly-function-not-working

Comment: @Tushar `$(course_number)` isn’t a syntax error but a reference error.

Comment: The reason it works in Firefox is that Firefox generates variables from the IDs of elements for the elements themselves. `course_number` is equivalent to the element with that ID. This only works in quirks mode, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle so it actually has a chance to work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/LjLhzd4g/10/

I've tested this in IE11 and Safari.

The main problem was that `$(course_number)` should be `$('#course_number')`.